# merging two lists with diff structures C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects with structure

```
string source, string target, int count
```

Sample data:

```
sourcea      targeta      10
sourcea      targetb      15
sourcea      targetc      20
```

My other list of objects is with structure

```
string source, int addnvalueacount, int addnvaluebcount, int addnvalueccount
```

Sample data:

```
sourcea    10    25   35
```

I wish to change the second list to the first list structure and then do a union all(concat) with first list.

So result ought to look as below:

```
sourcea      targeta      10
sourcea      targetb      15
sourcea      targetc      20
sourcea      addnlvaluea  10
sourcea      addnlvalueb  25
sourcea      addnlvaluec  35
```

All help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Without any own approaches you won´t get muvh help here I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest `Concat` with `SelectMany`; providing you have

```
List<A> listA = new List<A> {
  new A ("sorcea", "targeta" , 10),
  new A ("sorcea", "targetb" , 15),
  new A ("sorcea", "targetc" , 20),
};

List<B> listB = new List<B> {
  new B ("sourcea", 10, 15, 35),
};
```

in order to `Concat` all you have to do is to add `SelectMany`:

```
var result = listA
  .Concat(listB
    .SelectMany(item => new [] { // turn single B item into three A
       new A(item.source, "addnvaluea", item.addnvalueacount),
       new A(item.source, "addnvalueb", item.addnvaluebcount),
       new A(item.source, "addnvaluec", item.addnvalueccount),   
      }));
```